# iOS - Crashes not getting logged with log “[Crashlytics:Crash] Reporting is disabled”

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to set up a new organization to make sure that Debug (debugger not attached) builds' crashes are not dirtying the production Crashlytics. For Debug builds, I use a different organization and a different one for Release. 
I am trying to achieve this by changing the API Keys & Build Secret. The problem that I'm facing is that with the new organization my crashes are not getting logged. I've double checked the API Key & Build Secret.

I see logs like these:

```
Crashlytics:Crash] Reporting is disabled 
[Crashlytics] Crash reporting could not be initialized
```

The code I'm using to initialize Crashlytics looks like this ->

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.start(withAPIKey: my_private_api_key), Answers.self])
```

The crash reporting is working fine with the older organization, it's just the newer organization that's causing issues.

I've seen a previous question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875788/crashlyticscrash-reporting-is-disabled) and done a fair bit of researching + trial and error but I've not been able to find a solution.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We would need to know the bundle id/package name of your app to dig into this more. The most likely scenario is we haven't seen a build and run of the app with the correct set of keys. Contacting support(at)fabric(dot)io will likely get you the best help for this.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeBonnell. I've sent an email for the same.